# Modelling Capacity Constraint in CPLEX

Tags: constraints, cplex

[Capacity constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYhV9.png)

This is the constraint that I am trying to code out.
Given that
L is the set of all operations l
K is the set of all workcenters k
L(k) is the set of operations l processed on workcenter k

```
float ProcessingTime[Products][Operations] = ...;
float Capacity[Workshops] = ...;

dvar int+ Y[Products][0..NbOperations][Periods];

{string} Products = ...;
{string} Workshops = ...;
int NbOperations = ...; range Operations = 1..NbOperations;
int NbPeriods = ...; range Periods = 1..NbPeriods;
subject to
{
  forall(t in Periods,k in Workshops)
  ct5:
    sum(p in Products,l in Operations) (ProcessingTime[p][l]*Y[p][l][t]) <= Capacity[k];
}
```

One of the summation is supposed to be in terms of L(k), but I am not able to code it out here. Because l is in int while k is a string. Another thing is that L is already in use, I dont know how I can link these two together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing.

.mod

```
{string} Products = ...;
{string} Workshops = ...;
int NbOperations = ...; 
range Operations = 1..NbOperations;
int NbPeriods = ...; 
range Periods = 1..NbPeriods;

float ProcessingTime[Products][Operations] = ...;
float Capacity[Workshops] = ...;
{int} L[Workshops]=...;


dvar int+ Y[Products][0..NbOperations][Periods];
subject to
{
  forall(t in Periods,k in Workshops)
  ct5:
    sum(p in Products,l in Operations:l in L[k]) (ProcessingTime[p][l]*Y[p][l][t]) <= Capacity[k];
}
```

.dat

```
Products = {P1 P2 P3};
NbOperations = 10;
NbPeriods = 3;
Workshops={"A","B"};
Capacity=[1,2];
ProcessingTime=[[1],[2]];
L=[{1,2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10}];
```